# "Select" Orders from todays date

Tags: mysql

I have a table within mysql with orders stored in it. I have figured out how to pull everything I need with my SELECT statment. However, I was wondering, does anyone know how to grab orders only from today or even for the week using mysql? The table does contain an "order_date" field which is populated.

Comment: what is the type of order_date? date, datetime, int?

Comment: @sahid, the format of order_date is datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
... WHERE order_date = CURDATE(); // today
... WHERE order_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE(); // in the week
```

Comment: Yeah I looked and the order_date seems to be like: 2011-06-28 12:49:59 ... I tried the curdate, and it returned nothing. So I presume the issue is now my format?

Comment: Ok so you need to cast order_date in DATE like this: `WHERE DATE(order_date) = CURDATE()`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking (not knowing your schema):

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date >= $start_date AND order_date <= $end_date
```

You need to define $start_date and $end_date

Comment: Oh, thanks @AJ, now I need to look up the php function for date. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_date`) = DATE(NOW())
```

If the order_date is in datetime

**EDIT**

For a week

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_date`) >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```